# How best to DRY up this Rspec code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, refactoring, dry

I have the following Rspec code which I think can be DRY'ed up quite a bit, specifically the `check_creation_email_sent` and `check_rename_email_sent` methods, I just don't know how to do it.

I tried doing it with `shared_examples` and `it_behaves_like` but got the error `undefined method it_behaves_like...` so I'm hoping someone can shed some light for me.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CreateTopicFolder do
  let(:ids) { [123,456] }

  def clear_bucket(topic_id)
    subject.find_folder(topic_id).each { |obj| obj.delete } unless subject.find_folder(topic_id).nil?
  end

  def check_folder_and_object(topic_id, permalink, old_permalink=nil)
    folder = subject.find_folder(topic_id)
    folder.should_not be_empty
    folder.size.should == 1

    object = folder.first
    object.key.should include(permalink)
    object.key.should_not include(old_permalink) unless old_permalink.nil?
  end

  def check_creation_email_sent(email, permalink)
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.should_not be_empty

    email.subject.should match("Folder for '#{permalink}' created")
    email.body.should include("(You can reply to this e-mail to contact Engineering if something doesn't look right)")
  end

  def check_rename_email_sent(email, permalink, old_permalink)
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.should_not be_empty

    email.subject.should match("Folder for '#{old_permalink}' renamed to '#{permalink}'")
    email.body.should include("(You can reply to this e-mail to contact Engineering if something doesn't look right)")
  end

  before(:all) do
    ids.each { |folder| clear_bucket(folder) }
    permalink = "123-How-to-Have-Fun"
    subject.create_or_rename_folder(permalink)
  end

  it 'should find an existing folder in the S3 bucket if it exists' do
    subject.find_folder(123).should_not be_empty
  end

  it 'should create a new folder with the topic permalink as name if none already exists' do
    subject.find_folder(456).should be_nil

    permalink = "456-How-to-Not-Have-Any-Fun"
    subject.create_or_rename_folder(permalink)
    email = subject.instance_variable_get(:@email)

    check_creation_email_sent(email, permalink)
    check_folder_and_object(456, permalink)
  end

  it 'should rename an existing folder with new permalink' do
    subject.find_folder(456).should_not be_empty

    permalink = "456-How-to-Have-Fun-Again"
    old_permalink = subject.instance_variable_get(:@old_permalink)
    subject.create_or_rename_folder(permalink)
    email = subject.instance_variable_get(:@email)

    check_rename_email_sent(email, permalink, old_permalink)
    check_folder_and_object(456, permalink, old_permalink)
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `shared_examples_for("a thing")` and `it_should_behave_like("a thing")`.

Comment: Yes, and I tried that but got the `undefined method` error I mentioned in my post.

Comment: You said that you had tried `shared_examples` and `it_behaves_like`, not `it_should_behave_like`

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried `shared_examples/shared_examples_for` and `it_behaves_like/it_should_behave_like`. Same error with each combination.

Comment: How about refactoring the `check_folder_and_object` and `check_rename_email_sent` into [rspec matchers](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/custom-matchers) so that you can use `it { should send_rename_email }` or `it { should send_rename_email.with_email(@email) }`, etc.?

Comment: I'll give that a shot first thing!

Comment: Also, as a best practice you should have a single `should` per spec, so that each check will be run and failures won't be hidden by other failures. Your setup can be in a `before` block within a `context` to keep things DRY.